# Is Subdomain Site and Main Website Bad or Good?

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics, wordpress

I have had a subdomain website for about 2 years built on wix. It is on page 1 for some related keywords.
Let's say the website is specific to **sports cars**.

- Example URL: sports-cars.mywebsite.com

I also have a main website that has been live for about 2 years built on wordpress.
Let's say the website is about automobiles. The website has a section built for trucks, **sports cars**, sedans, SUVs, ect...

The main website did not have all of the specific vehicle types built out at first, and I just now finished adding **sports cars** to the main website.

- Example URL: www.mywebsite.com/sports-cars
- Example URL: www.mywebsite.com/sports-cars/v8
- Example URL: www.mywebsite.com/sports-cars/v12
- ect...

Questions:

1. Is there anything bad about having the subdomain still live? It does not have duplicate content.
2. Anything to back up why I should get rid of the subdomain site?

I do not like how the subdomain is a wix site and I am not able to capture leads (I do not have Google Analytics on this subdomain site), like I can on my main wordpress site. So I don't really have a way to know how the site is performing.